# What are some examples of magnetocaloric materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity

I've recently become fascinated with a cryo cooling method known as "magnetic refrigeration". [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration) is the Wikipedia article. I was wondering if there is a list of magnetocaloric materials.

Specifically, I was wondering if the chemical compound Yittrium Barium Copper Oxide (YBCO), a high-temperature superconductor, is in this list. It would be wonderful to refrigerate this superconductor with magnetism rather than with (disposable) liquid nitrogen. Whereas the liquid nitrogen would be used up, a magnetic refrigeration setup only consumes electricity and is a more permanent solution to refrigerating the superconductor.

Answer (score 3):

Any material that undergoes a phase transition of its magnetic properties could be used as a magnetic refrigerant. This transition happens at a temperature called "Curie" temperature. This would be analogous to the boiling temperature of a liquid used in conventional vapor-compressor refrigerators.

The transition temperature defines to some extent the hot and cold end temperatures of the refrigerator. This type of refrigeration is apparently very efficient, but needs of a high magnetic field to magnetize intermittently the magnetocaloric material.

There is increasing interest to apply this technology for ambient temperature cooling. Many prototypes have been built using Gadolinium metal. See imugica.com for more details on the mathematical modelling of such machines

Answer (score 3):

To complete the previous answer, more and more magnetic and structural anisotropic material are being discovered.

These present different magnetic state/magnetization (and also behaviors as well, which can be exploited away from $T_c$) depending on how the cristal magnetic axis are aligned according to a magnetic field. Such families would includes Mg compounds such as the RMnO$_3$ and RMn$_2$O$_5$ (R stands for rare earths which are REALLY interesting for MCE and RMCE) or thin films such as FeGaTe3 or Fe$_{5-x}GeTe_y$. A recent study was able to directly measure rotative magnetocaloric effect (RMCE) and is promising as a technology.

> I'd like to add that a lot of RMnO$_3$ and RMn$_2$O$_5$ were done by Patrick Fournier and Mohammed Balli, starting with the HoMn$_2$O$_5$ in 2014

> I'd like to add a note that thin films materials are yet to be tested for MCE and RMCE unfortunately. The main focus/use for them, nowadays, are in spintronics and related domains in reason of the niche use for them and the difficulty to grow such crystals.

Hope it answers your question a bit more. Cheers.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the "recent study".

Comment: Yes,there is a master thesis published in 2021 (which is fairly recent) at University of Sherbrooke, Qc, which focuses on direct measurement of RMCE. You can ask Pr. Patrick Fournier about it